# Jersey 2.27 - Do not receive JSON in case of error handling using ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

**Bean-Component for Credential entry form**

```
  public class UserCredentials {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public UserCredentials() {
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**resource**

```
@Path("auth")
   public class AuthenticationResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @PermitAll
    public Response authenticateUserName(UserCredentials credentials)  {

        EmployeeDao dao = new EmployeeDaoImpl();
        Employee email = dao.loadEmployeeByFieldStr("email", credentials.getUsername());

        if(email == null){
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Non found!");
        }

        credentials.setUsername(email.getEmail());
        Response response = Response.ok(credentials).build();

        return response;
    }
```

**model for storing error details**

```
@JsonInclude( JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ApiErrorDetails {

    private Integer status;
    private String title;
    private String message;
    private String path;

    public ApiErrorDetails() {
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }


}
```

**ExceptionMapper**

```
     @Provider
       public class AccessDeniedExceptionMapper 
              implements   ExceptionMapper<AccessDeniedException> {

        @Context
        private UriInfo uriInfo;

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(AccessDeniedException exception) {


            Response.Status status = Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED; 

            ApiErrorDetails errorDetails = new ApiErrorDetails();

            errorDetails.setStatus(status.getStatusCode());
            errorDetails.setTitle(status.getReasonPhrase());
            errorDetails.setMessage(exception.getMessage());


            errorDetails.setPath(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getPath());

            Response.ResponseBuilder statusResponse = Response.status(status);
            Response.ResponseBuilder entity =  
                                        statusResponse.entity(errorDetails);
            Response.ResponseBuilder type = 
                              entity.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            Response response = type.build();

            return response;
        }
    }
```

**registration config**

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/*")
public class JerseyConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        packages("com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest");
        register(AuthenticationResource.class);
        register(AccessDeniedExceptionMapper.class);
        register(AuthenticationExceptionMapper.class);
        register(DataNotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.rest.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>     
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlets.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

When **RuntimeException** strikes, it must be intercepted by Jersey classes that implement the **ExceptionMapper** interface.

During debugging, I observed how the **response** was formed with the details of the errors in the **AccessDeniedExceptionMapper** class.
 But on the client side, I only get the status code, which is all set, and instead of the **JSON** object with the details of the errors, here are the empty parentheses {}.

Why?

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

In ExceptionMapper class:

```
Response.Status status = Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED;
```

`status` is a static final enum variable set as `Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED`. It is set as a single value. You cannot use get methods on a value like this, as it doesn't have getter methods. I suspect the next few lines:

```
ApiErrorDetails errorDetails = new ApiErrorDetails();

            errorDetails.setStatus(status.getStatusCode());
            errorDetails.setTitle(status.getReasonPhrase());
            errorDetails.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
```

aren't actually doing anything. `status.getStatusCode()`,`status.getReasonPhrase()`,`status.getMessage()` do not return anything, as the getter methods above are not part of `Response.status` class but of `ApiErrorDetails`. You should use `Response` getter methods and choose which is the appropriate data to set.

Answer (score 0):

```
                             Solution
```

**The resource**

```
@Provider
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Path("auth")
public class AuthenticationResource {

    @POST
    @PermitAll
    @Path("username")
    public Response authenticateUserName(UserCredentials credentials)  {

        EmployeeDao dao = new EmployeeDaoImpl();
        Employee email = dao.loadEmployeeByFieldStr("email", credentials.getUsername());

        if(email == null){
            throw new DataNotFoundException("An object not found!!!!!!");
        }

        credentials.setUsername(email.getEmail());
        Response response = Response.ok(credentials).build();

        return response;
    }
...
```

**class exception**

```
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public DataNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

- change the library **jersey-media-json-jackson** and instead to put the library **jackson-jaxrs-json-provider**.
- The error detail class must be have all setters and getters.

and

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 public class ApiErrorDetails {

    private Integer status;
    private String title;
    private String message;
    private String path;

    public ApiErrorDetails() {
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

The **JacksonJsonProvider.class** must be registered

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        packages("com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest");
        register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);

    }
}
```

Remember, that you must to put the annotation @**Provider** on custom **ExceptionMappers**, that you are using.

```
@Provider
public class DataNotFoundExceptionMapper <E> implements ExceptionMapper<DataNotFoundException> {

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(DataNotFoundException exception) {
        return getResponseException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND, exception);
    }

    private <E> Response  getResponseException(Response.Status status, E exceptionSource ){

        Throwable exception = (Throwable) exceptionSource;

        ApiErrorDetails errorDetails = new ApiErrorDetails();

        errorDetails.setStatus(status.getStatusCode());
        errorDetails.setTitle(status.getReasonPhrase());
        errorDetails.setMessage(exception.getMessage());

        errorDetails.setPath(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getPath());

        Response.ResponseBuilder statusResponse = Response.status(status);
        Response.ResponseBuilder entity = statusResponse.entity(errorDetails);
        Response.ResponseBuilder type = entity.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = type.build();

        return response;
    }
}
```

The method getResponseException() can be to write into another class, for example
ClassUtils.

If you know how to do better, write here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p81cT.png)